# Add new field To collection in MongoDB but the value based on value in another field

Tags: mongodb

How Can I add New Field To All Documents but Tha Value Based On value in Another Field?
Example :

{"_id":"1","city":"Amman"}
{"_id":"2","city":"Cairo"}

I Want to Add a new field to all documents (Capital) based on the city name if the city is Amman Capital will be true else false

Answer (score 0):

I think what you trying to achieve is to add new field to each document based on the existing details in each of those document. Try this script with your collection details:

```js
   use YourDB;
   db.YourCollection.find({}).forEach(function(doc){
      if(doc.city =='whatever'){
         doc.capital=true;
      }else{
         doc.capital=false;
      }
      db.YourCollection.save(doc);
    });
```